# Why such upper bound for the number of elements in this set?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm going through some text on number theory. And I don't understand one statement.

There is a set $S=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots s_n\}$. A function $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is defined, and it is proven that $f(s)\in[1,10^6]$ for $s\in S$. Moreover, it is proved that if $f(s_1)=f(s_2)=\ldots=f(s_j)$, then $j\le 2^7$.

And then the author makes the leap that these two properties imply $|S|<2^7\cdot 10^6$, where $|S|$ is the number of elements of $S$. And I don't really understeand why.

Could somebody explain this to me?

Comment: The conclusion should be $\le$ unless there is more information.

Answer (score 1):

There are at most $2^7$ elements which map to each value, and there are $10^6$ values to choose from.